# RelativeLayout -> match_parent is not the same size with parent view

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I've made a simple application to illustrate my problem. Brief explanation:
the app contains only one activity. It's root view is TableLayout. The latter is filled with TableRow elements which are, in turn, inflated from "row.xml". Here is code:

TestActivity.java

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
    TableLayout table=new TableLayout(this);
    setContentView(table);
    TableRow row; 
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        row=(TableRow)inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null, true);
        table.addView(row);
    }

  }
}
```

In row.xml TableRow is root element, it has a child - RelativeLayout. Pay attention to RelativeLayout's property android:layout_width="match_parent".
row.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/background"
>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/announcement_row_relative_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     >
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then I run the project, open hierarchyViewer tool and inspect width of table rows and corresponding relative layouts - I see 320 and 0 respectively. Why aren't they the same (320 and 320) if I declared "match_parent" in relative layout? I attach 2 images where you can observe width of the elements by your own.

[image: TableRow width]
[image: RelativeLayout width]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here : `row=(TableRow)inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null, true);`

You have to inflate your row like this:

```
row=(TableRow)inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, table, false);
```

This way the `LayoutParams` will get loaded from your XML file.

Comment: I tried to change that line to "row=(TableRow)inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, table, false);
", but hierarchyviewer still showed width=0. Then I tried line "row=(TableRow)inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, table, true);" and got error "java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TableLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TableRow
"

Comment: But what are your TableLayout LauoutParams? I don't see where are you setting them in your code..

Comment: I did it in different way: I deleted TableRow tag from XML file and attached RelativeLayout to row in code. When I did that, row width was 320, relative layout width was 317. That is almost OK but still strange.

Comment: Are TableLayout LauoutParams important? I don't set them so they are default I suppore, but whatever they are, TableRow width is 320 so it should be the same with RelativeLayout width.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because your RelativeLayout contains no children and its `onMeasure(..)` method hasn't provided any desired width.

Comment: If I add children, my relative layout's width becomes equal to widest child. However, that still is not TableRow's width. Why? I want relative layout to match_parent.